# Webstorm 5.0.4 >No code color options

Tags: webstorm

I am using the trial version of Webstorm 5.0.4 - as far as I know the trial is not limited in any way other than the 30-day period.

Under `Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts`, It's supposed to have a section for each code type (HTML, Javascript etc) so one can edit the code coloring for each.

Mine doesn't have any of these. How do I enable them?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try to reinstall the IDE, could be some corrupted installation or a broken plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, mine seems fine (also a trial).  I have a full listing of options.  And yes, the trial versions don't have any inherent limitations over the full release, besides the time limit.

Give the EAP a try: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+6+EAP  This is the beta for WebStorm 6, but it's worth seeing if the issue goes away.

Comment: Being a beta, is it stable enough for heavy use?